# Error: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I build a flutter app but run into error
[image]

```
/C:/Users/david.huang/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sync_scroll_library-1.0.1/lib/src/gesture/gesture_state_mixin.dart:6:49: Error: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided.
final PageMetrics _testPageMetrics = PageMetrics(
                                                ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:266:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  PageMetrics({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

The widget `PageMetrics` is Flutter SDK original widget so I cant modify it

I have tried invalidate Caches and restart but still not work.

Has anyone also encountered this problem?

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this one if you error is related to material_floating_search_bar...

```
https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar_2
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue after updating to the latest version of flutter on the master channel. The devicePixelRatio argument was changed to required in the latest version, so one of my packages that was using it was no longer compatible. In my case it was the material_floating_search_bar package, I ended up just dropping the package as I no longer needed it. For you, you probably need to update to the latest [sync_scroll_library](https://pub.dev/packages/sync_scroll_library). If that is still incompatible you may need to either drop the library, create an issue and/or a PR for the library to get it updated, or use an earlier version of flutter for the time being.

Comment: I wonder what are the packages similar to material_floating_search_bar

Answer (score 1):

In my case (flutter 3.7.0 -> 3.10.2)

Updating the `wechat_assets_picker` 8.4.0 -> 8.5.0

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Android Studio > External Libraries > Dart Packages > sync_scroll_library-1.0.1 > src > gesture > gesture_state_mixin.dart
to make
`

```
final PageMetrics _testPageMetrics = PageMetrics(
  axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
  minScrollExtent: 0,
  maxScrollExtent: 10,
  pixels: 5,
  viewportDimension: 10,
  viewportFraction: 1.0,
  devicePixelRatio:1.0 // add this line
);
```

` and solved the problem.
Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when using the old package, which is material_floating_search_bar, but you have to delete it and use the new package, which is material_floating_search_bar_2, and the application will work after that without problems.
_You can view the new packages through this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar_2)